# Removing parallel edges from binary image

Tags: image-processing

[image: Binary Image]

This is a binary image. I want to remove the portion in the red region, and keep the one in the green region.

The red region has the property of double parallel edges, whereas green does not. If someone could suggest an algorithm it would be helpful.

Comment: Its not clear what your asking. Are you looking for a way to remove pixels from an already defined area, or are you looking for an algorithm for defining the area?

Comment: @slayton no I am talking about the whole image. I want to detect the parallel edges(the type inside red region). and set them to black

Comment: The problem that the "lines" are not really "parallel", first they are curved lines and are only approximately parallel to one another.

Comment: @nate - I know that they are not parallel. but in other words I can say that I want to remove the river like structures. I think now i am clear?

Comment: And I also assume you want to do it automatically, or is it just this one figure, or many similar figures? The more info you'll put the better people will understand what you need. Also, what have you tried to do already?

Comment: @nate - yes I have to implement this to other images also, but if something works on this, it will work on others also. I was trying something on moving a small kernel and finding lines based on hough transform.

Comment: Seems like a typical situation where Gabor wavelets might work.

Comment: @crack_addict I think you are one step too far in the pipeline, this might be able to be done better before thresholding. There looks like there are many double lines in the image, but with gaps due to the thresholding. IMO thresholding is towards the end of the pipeline. Can you post the image before this step?

Answer (score 2):

Just a suggestion:

1. perform binary skeletonization
2. detect lines as connected sets of pixels
3. for every line, find distance to nearest pixel on some other line
4. compute average distance between inspected line and the nearest line
5. if the computed distance lays within some predefined interval (say, 3-8 pixels), consider it a double-line and remove both lines

The interval can be determined statistically because double lines have distances forming a distribution, which can be separated well from other line distances in the image.